# Add Type to Operations in Papyrus Class diagram,

Tags: operation, papyrus

I just want to know how can I add a Type (for example String) to a Operation in Papyrus Class diagram.

Because if I drag a Operation form the palette to the Classe diagram, the Operation will be without any Return Type. (I want to show for example the Function String getName() in Class Diagram)

Thanks a lot

Regards

Comment: try owned Parameter as you can see  http://postimg.org/image/dsilpmfdb/ and then press + to view detailed properties. Hope it help you:)

Answer (score 3):

To clarify what user2019510 said:

An Owned Parameter can be:

- Method arguments/parameters for the method (e.g. the `name` in `aPerson.setName(String name)`) You can name these and/or set the type.
- Return values (as for `int anArray.size()`).

The "Direction" specifies its *intent*: is it an input parameter, an output parameter, an "inout" parameter (pass it in, get a different result out -- very useful for Fortran), or a return value.

You can name the parameters or omit the name. For return values, naming the Owned Parameter doesn't make sense to me, so I omit its name.

Hope this helps somebody!